# Removing Python 2.5 in Fedora

Tags: python, uninstall

I followed this tutorial http://paltman.com/2007/nov/15/getting-ssl-support-in-python-251/ and installed python 2.5. Now when I enter the python terminal it reads python 2.5 and not 2.6.

How do I remove python 2.5? So it reverts back to 2.6?

Python was 2.5 was installed by:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/64624/debian-python2-6-as-default may help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081698/transition-from-python2-4-to-python2-6-on-centos-module-migration-problem

Answer (score 1):

I doubt your make install overwrote version 2.6, so unless it did this can be fixed by simply re-organizing your PATH variable

Comment: How do i go about doing that?

Comment: @Phil: Step 1 -- Identify the OS you're working on.  Step 2 -- **Update** your question with the name of your operating system.  Step 3 -- Google for "PATH" settings and your OS name, and see what you get.  Step 4 -- Ask **Specific** questions on superuser.com for how to update OS settings.

Comment: This question would be better answered on superuser.com.
I assume you're on linux? 
`export PATH="/path/to/python/2.6:${PATH}"`

Comment: Yes, fedora. I just did a whereis python 2.6 and recieved a number of directores which one should I use?

Answer (score 0):

If you did `./configure` without a `--prefix`, Python will have been installed in `/usr/local` by default, so you could remove it with:

```
rm /usr/local/bin/python
```

however that will leave behind all sorts of other Python-related files in `/usr/local`. If Python is the only thing you have installed into `/usr/local`, it'll be easy to wipe it all by removing `/usr/local/bin/*`, `/usr/local/lib/*` and `/usr/local/include/*`. Otherwise, you'd have to be careful to remove only the Python-related files. That's all part of the fun of the wonderful Unix “install everything into the same folders” strategy (and why you typically do want to specify a `--prefix`.)

Answer (score 0):

When you type python into terminal it is looking for python in the search path ($PATH).  I have a few different versions of python on my computer. If I type python in to terminal, the interpreter for python2.6 opens.  If I run:

```
ls -l /usr/bin | grep "python"
```

I see this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root           9 2010-05-12 19:44 python -> python2.6
```

At least on my computer, the version found when I call python is called because that is what the symbolic link with the name "python" is linked to.  I am guessing you will see something similar on yours, except the link will be pointed at python2.5.  To fix this simply get rid of the current link and create a new link to the python2.6 file:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/bin/python
```

Of course, before you do that you should make sure that you have all the needed files (mainly, python2.5 and python2.6 should still be present in the /usr/bin directory).  There is also the chance that your python files are not in /usr/bin. There is nothing wrong with having multiple versions of python.  I have 2.5 (because I use it at work), 2.6, and 3 on mine.  If I want to use something other than the defaultthen I just direct it to that one.